# Transmission Spectrum of Rock

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, geophysics, absorption, imaging

Maybe a very specific question, but what wavelengths are sand grains transparent to?

Also, how can one image underground minerals through rock? Is there a certain Infrared band that sandstone (quartz, silica or silicon dioxide) is transparent to?

Comment: for example: https://science.sciencemag.org/content/310/5756/1925 works where there is no liquid water.